# Using TextOptions.TextFormattingMode with FormattedText

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

With WPF4 you can have non-blurry text by adding TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" and TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" to your xaml:

```
<Window
   TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
   TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased">
```

This works fine for me except for when I draw text with DrawingContext.DrawText like this:

```
void DrawText(DrawingContext dc)
{
  FormattedText ft = new FormattedText("Hello World",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
    FontSize,
    brush);
  dc.DrawText(ft, new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top));
}
```

How can I draw non-blurry text with FormattedText? ie I want TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" and TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" to be used.

Answer (score 13):

There's an overloaded constructor for `FormattedText` that allows specifying a `TextFormattingMode`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474866.aspx

```
void DrawText(DrawingContext dc)
{
  FormattedText ft = new FormattedText("Hello World",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
    System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch),
    FontSize,
    brush,
    null,
    TextFormattingMode.Display);
  dc.DrawText(ft, new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top));
}
```

Comment: +1. I agree, this answer is definitely right and I can't see a reason for a downvote. It doesn't specify how to set `TextRenderingMode` though

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example here for [Advanced Text Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754036.aspx) and create a TextFormatter object and use TextLine.Draw()